# How can I move something at 1/4 speed of another object using floats?

Tags: java

I am making Pac-Man and I am having some issues getting the ghost to go a bit faster than Pac-Man.  The ghost class has 4 if statements for each direction but before it starts to move the ghost in the desired direction it checks if it is on a tile and not halfway through one with this `(x/tileSize) % 1==0` It does the same thing for the y as well.  When I change the ghost velocity from 1 to 1.2 (to make it go a bit faster than Pac-Man at 1) the above code does not work and the ghost gets stuck because `System.out.println((x/tileSize) % 1)` prints some long float like `0.00451256` I was thinking about making 2 different classes that keep the game time, one for Pac-Man and one for the ghosts so I can just update it slower but that does not seem like a good way of doing it to me.  If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to show a [mcve] of the code. We don't know what GUI framework you're using or how things "move"

Comment: If you move your items by floating point amounts you must switch away from "is item exactly here" conditions to "has item moved past this point since the last update" or "is item in the general vincinity of this point" or something like that.